# jQuery how to disable click function for row when clicking on the first td element?

Tags: jquery

My jQuery:

```
$('table tbody tr').live('click', function(){
 window.open($(this).data('url'));
 });
```

Example of HTML row:

```
<tr style="height:50px;" data-url="https://www.google.com">
<td class="checkit"><input id="task_ids_" name="task_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="126"></td>
    <td style="width: 100px;text-align:left;">Name </td>
    <td>69 øre</td>
    <td>20 øre</td>
    <td>5.0 kr.<br>2.5 kr.</td>
    <td>100 </td>
    <td>59 kr. </td>
    <td>59 kr.</td>
    <td></td>
                        </tr>
```

My problem is that the link is activated, when I click on the first column with the checkbox. How do I disable the click function for the first td column with the checkbox?

Comment: `live` was deprecated years ago, and removed a while back, for quite good reasons. I recommend upgrading to a recent version of jQuery and using `on` (or `delegate`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `:not` in the selector:

```
$('table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)').live('click', function(){
```

Also, `.live` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery.